# angular-ui bootstrap $modal service using directive instead

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

The examples I see of using angular-ui/bootstrap's `$modal` always look something like this:

```
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'modaltemplate.html',
        controller: function($scope) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

What if I want to use a directive, instead? Like this:

```
    $modal.open({
        template: '<my-modal-directive></my-modal-directive>'
        // no "controller" property; use directive's controller
    });
```

The markup for `my-modal-directive` renders fine, and I've moved the `controller` property into the `my-modal-directive` definition object, but now getting this error from the `my-modal-directive`:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $modalInstanceProvider <- $modalInstance
```

Can anyone point me to an example where `$modal` uses a directive where that directive defines the `controller`?

For example, this works, where I've replaced the `templateUrl` with a directive:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/YrGaF83GH6bzZPRR55GK?p=preview
```

But when I move the controller from `$modal.open()` into the directive, that's when the error happens:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/aLBT239EpL004DRh4jll?p=preview
```

Comment: Are you using $modal inside of that directive or controller?

Comment: Using `$modal` in the controller that launches the modal. Using `$modalInstance` in the `my-modal-directive`'s controller. :)

Comment: I dont understand why u think that this is possible and why u need it. Adding directive to modal (your 1st step) is clear and usual, but 2nd?

Comment: As Sergiu points out, angular-ui bootstrap uses an imperative approach. Defining a template and controller inline with `$modal.open()` vs. encapsulating what's opened in a single directive isn't a great design. You've fragmented what the modal is by breaking it into two separate pieces--a template, and a controller. Encapsulation is a better pattern than composition in this case, in my opinion. Using a directive that's a component (i.e. isolate scope, template, controller all in directive definition) for the modal to launch, should be preferred.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you have is that you are trying to inject values which are not available for injection. Only values registered with the injector can be injected.

The logic of you code is also flawed, you are creating the modal in your main controller but trying to close it in the directive. Ideally, the modal should be triggered by the directive (via it's link function), and then you can ok/cancel it from there.

See my http://plnkr.co/edit/3p1rXAymd7BilyklgxKy?p=preview for one possible approach, I have kept the code that closes and cancels the modal in the main controller.

```
    angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').directive('myModal', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.selected = {
            item: $scope.items[0] 
          };
        }
    };
});
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {
    var modalInstance;
    var modalScope = $scope.$new();
    modalScope.ok = function () {
            modalInstance.close(modalScope.selected);
    };
    modalScope.cancel = function () {
            modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };      

    modalInstance = $modal.open({
      template: '<my-modal></my-modal>',
      size: size,
      scope: modalScope
      }
    );

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});
```

Comment: This in essence means _stop trying not to use `$modal`s controller_.

Comment: Yes, as you really have no means of getting access to it in your directives template/controller.

Comment: Slight confusion as I though you meant access to the $modal controller, and not access to scope variables. I still think that it would be preferable to create a self contained directive to which you can pass a template, and ok/close methods via attributes on the directive. If I have time I might create a suitable directive.

Comment: Yup, you are right, that would be the more elegant way, encapsulating the whole `$modal` and `$modalInstance` code into a self-contained directive. I think the more "imperative" API bootstrap-ui exposes is bad practice and against what AngularJS advocates for.

Comment: I certainly like this approach you've done in http://plnkr.co/edit/5wV6XTtkhnZkmhETBjkv?p=preview better, Sergui, than the accepted answer. All the controller logic now lives in the `myModal` directive, where it belongs. In the accepted solution, the controller logic that belongs in `myModal` is defined in the controller that `$modal`, which is a poor separation of concerns. Nicely done!

Comment: I like what is going on here @SergiuParaschiv.  I do not quite follow how you avoided using the directive name.  I might be missing it, but I see the open function being called.  I do not see myModal as an attribute or as an element.

Comment: With my structure making it configurable is a matter of string concatenation though, right?

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that `$modalInstance` can only be injected in the controller that you provide to `$modal.open`.
Check out the sources [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js#L377):

```
$modal.open = function (modalOptions) {
    ...
    var modalInstance = {
        ...
    };
    ...
    if (modalOptions.controller) {
        ...
        ctrlLocals.$modalInstance = modalInstance;
        ...
        ctrlInstance = $controller(modalOptions.controller, ctrlLocals);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In essence when you try to add `$modalInstance` as a dependency to your controller AngularJS looks for a registered global provider named `$modalInstanceProvider`. Now the trouble is, if you understood the code above, that `$modalInstance` is *not* a globally registered provider. It only "exists" as a dependency for the controller you pass to `$modal.open`.

If you read the rest of the code you'll notice that `$modal.open` returns `modalInstance`, maybe you can use that.

Something like [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/5wV6XTtkhnZkmhETBjkv?p=preview):

```
function SomeController($modal) {
    $scope.modal = {
        instance: null
    };

    $scope.modal.instance = $modal.open({
        template: '<my-modal-directive modal="modal"></my-modal-directive>',
        scope: $scope
    });
}

function MyModalDirective() {
    scope: {
        modal: '='
    },
    link: function($scope) {
         // here you can access $scope.modal.instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I create a directive to create modals easily. A modal content is based on a template view.

```
angular.module('your_app').directive('modalViewUrl', function ($modal) {

    return {
        restrict: 'A', // A: attribute
        scope: { // isolate scope
            'modalViewUrl': '@', // modal view url to render the modal content
            'modalController': '@' // modal view controller (optional)
        },
        link: function($scope, element, attrs){

            element.bind('click', function(){

                var template = 
                    '<div class="modal-body">' + 
                    '<button ng-click="$close()" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">' +
                    '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>' +
                    '</button>' +
                    '<div ng-include="\'' + $scope.modalViewUrl + '\'"></div>' +
                    '</div>';

                // see modal reference from ui bootstrap at <http://angular-ui.github.io>
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    animation: true,
                    template: template,
                    controller: $scope.modalController,                    
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Example how to use it:

**index.html**

```
<a modal-view-url="hello.html" modal-controller="HelloCtrl" href="#">
    Click here to open the modal
</a>
```

**hello.html**

```
<h1> Hello World {{name}} </h1>
```

**HelloCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('HelloCtrl', 
                function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    // $modalInstance: same from  from ui bootstrap
    $scope.name = "Xico";
});
```

A modal view can have its own controller. Example:

**hello.html (modified)**

```
<h1 ng-controller="Hello2Ctrl"> {{msg}} {{name}} </h1>
```

**Hello2Ctrl.js**

```
angular.module('yourApp').controller('Hello2Ctrl', 
                function ($scope) {
    $scope.msg = "Hello Worldsszz";
    $scope.name = "Zefa";
});
```

Observe that the modal output will be "Hello Worldsszz Xico", because the modal controller (HelloCtrl) will be rendered after view controller (Hello2).

[Reference](https://github.com/dndlab/dndlab.github.io/blob/angular/app/scripts/directives/modal.js)

Comment: Where does hello html come from?  Why is it necessary?.  I think your link function is very clever.

Answer (score 2):

It's even more late reply, but someone may find it useful.

I have enhanced Fernando Felix answer and made my own quite flexible directive which communicates with the controller, which I think might be solution for this question.

**Directive**

```
var modalUrl = function ($modal) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // A: attribute
        scope: { // isolate scope
            'modalUrl': '@', // modal view url to render the modal content
            'modalController': '@', // modal view controller (optional)
            'value': "="
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            console.log('modalUrl link');

            var modalInstance;
            var template = [
                    '<div class="modal-body">',
                        '<button ng-click="$close()" type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close">',
                            '<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>',
                        '</button>',
                        '<div ng-include="\'' + scope.modalUrl + '\'"></div>',
                    '</div>'
                ].join('');


            element.bind('click', function(){
                // see modal reference from ui bootstrap at <http://angular-ui.github.io>
                modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    size: attrs.size,
                    animation: true,
                    template: template,
                    resolve: {
                        params: function () {
                            console.log('value passed to modal:');
                            console.log(scope.value);
                            return scope.value;
                        }
                    },
                    controller: scope.modalController
                });

                modalInstance.result.then(
                    function (returnValue) {
                        // alert('value: '+returnValue);
                        console.log('modal returnValue:');
                        console.log(returnValue);
                        scope.value = returnValue;
                    }, function () {
                        console.log('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                    }
                );

            });

        }
    };
}
modalUrl.$inject = ['$modal'];
angular.module('app').directive('modalUrl', modalUrl);
```

**Controller**

```
var HelloCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance, modalVal) {
    // $modalInstance: same from  from ui bootstrap
    console.log('Hello init!');
    // modalVal is the init modal value passed via directive
    console.log(modalVal);

    // your code
    $scope.name = modalVal;

    $scope.ok = function() {                                        
        $modalInstance.close(this.name); // returnValue
    };

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
}
HelloCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$modalInstance','params'];
angular.module('app').controller('HelloCtrl',HelloCtrl);
```

**inline template**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="hello.html">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />                                        
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

It's one controller and template per popup type, then you can call it multiple times with:

```
<a modal-url="hello.html" modal-controller="HelloCtrl" value="yourVal" ng-init="yourVal='test'" href="#">Click here to open the modal</a>
```

You can initialize value with whatever - ie. object, array etc.

**or external template**

Pretty much the same, just url changes and template file is used for template.

```
<a modal-url="/modal/test1.html" modal-controller="HelloCtrl" value="yourVal" ng-init="yourVal='test'" href="#">Click here to open the modal</a>
```

test1.html

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name" />                                        
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

**Modal size etc.**

Just add parameter size="sm|lg" for the modal link/button ie.
Click here to open the modal
For standard size skip the parameter.
You may enhance it yourself using link function attrs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm kanda late replay put simplest way is to use

```
$scope.$parent.$close(result);

$scope.$parent.$dismiss(reason);
```

This works form your directive controller.